# Rename node in XML file and give it parmeters?

Tags: c#, xml

I have created a xml file from a dataset, but the first node is `<NewDataset>` i need to change that to `<FormData>` and i also need to add in some parameter like Platform="Android" and Version="488".

Is there any way to change it while it is still a dataset or will i have to call up the file after i change it and then save it?

My knowledge of data files is minimal and i really need some help.

---

Current xml file

```
<NewDataSet>
  <FieldData>
    <property_details_gps_location>-29.77861, 31.008617</property_details_gps_location>
    <property_details_address_address1>27 MANJEE</property_details_address_address1>
    <property_details_address_address2>KENVILLE</property_details_address_address2>
    <property_details_address_city>ETHEKWINI</property_details_address_city>
    <property_details_address_state>KWAZULU NATAL</property_details_address_state>
  </FieldData>
</NewDataSet>
```

---

What i hope to achive:

```
<FormData Platform="Android" PlatformVersion="73" Version="488" DataVersion="1" Description="Investec - Res" FormId="d617a5e8-b49b-4640-9734-bc7a2bf05691" FileId="bce3a788-6725-4ce2-b965-1b55c6e7cc95" EncryptionVerification="" CreatedBy="Shaunm" EditedBy="Shaunm">
  <FieldData>
    <property_details_gps_location>-29.77861, 31.008617</property_details_gps_location>
    <property_details_address_address1>27 MANJEE</property_details_address_address1>
    <property_details_address_address2>KENVILLE</property_details_address_address2>
    <property_details_address_city>ETHEKWINI</property_details_address_city>
    <property_details_address_state>KWAZULU NATAL</property_details_address_state>
  </FieldData>
</FormData>
```

Comment: First of all, show the code where you build the Xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily modify/add elements/attributes via LINQ to XML.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(dataSetObject.GetXml());
 doc.Root.Name  = "FormData ";
 doc.Root.Add(new XAttribute("Platform", "Android"));
 ...
 doc.Save("sample.xml");
```

To list the child nodes,

```
foreach (XElement element in doc.Root.Element("FieldData").Descendants())
 {
   Console.WriteLine(element.Name + " : " + element.Value );
  }
```

Comment: Hey thanks that does look easy, I added it to my code, but where does it save to?

Comment: With doc. i can only access the root and next and previous, i would i add the Xattribute (IncludeInPDFExport="Yes") to all the child nodes?

Comment: It all looks to be working at the moment, i just cant find where it saves, once i know that i can award you with the green tick.

Comment: @Pommy - By default it will be saved in `bin/debug` if app is winform. However you need to specify absolute path to save XML. eg. `doc.Save(@"c:\sample.xml");`

Comment: How do i get to the childNodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSL-T to effect a simple transformation on the original stream.  Once you have it you can write it or manipulate it in memory.